# Javascript Regex to avoid same character twice consecutively

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to avoid having the same character(@ is the character) twice consecutively but can have them at muliple places.
For example:

```
someword@someword is ok
someword@@someword is not ok
someword@someword@someword is ok too.
```

So basically this is my existing regular expression `/^([a-zA-Z0-9'\-\x80-\xff\*\+ ]+),([a-zA-Z0-9'\-\x80-\xff\*\+\@ ]+)$/` where the first group is the last name and second group is the first name. I have introduced a magical character @ in the first name group which I will replace with a space when saving. The problem is I cannot have consecutive @ symbols.

Comment: and what have you tried??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.replace(/@@/g,'@')
```

finds and replaces all instances of '@@' by '@'. Also works if you have more than 2 consecutive '@' signs. Doesn't replace single @ signs or things that aren't @ signs.

edit: if you don't have to replace but just want to test on it:

```
/@@/.test(str)
```

Answer (score 6):

Looks for any repeated characters (repeated once):

```
/(.)\1/.test(string) // returns true if repeated characters are found
```

Looks for a repeated @:

```
string.indexOf('@@') !== -1 // returns true if @@ is found
```

Comment: This matches _any_ repeated character. I think the question is specifically about the @ character. You might want to address that in your answer.

Comment: @Reeno sorry about that. I just wanted to explain more.

Answer (score 3):

```
str.replace(/(@{2,})/g,'@')
```

works for any number of occorences.. @@, @@@, @@@@ etc

Comment: replace looks fine too. I can even look for consecutive @s at the back end too. But I wanted it in the regex as I have a particular set of characters allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

```
/^(?!.*(.)\1)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d@]*$/
```

This regex will not allow @ consecutively

Comment: This matches _any_ repeated character. I think the question is specifically about the @ character. You might want to address that in your answer.

Comment: made the changes, have a look

Comment: @RajdeepSingh I tried again, it still doesn't allow _any_ successive characters

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any pure regex solution that worked for your use-case

So here is mine:

```
^([a-z0-9]@?)*[a-z0-9]$
 |____________|______|
       |          |-> Makes sure your string ends with an alphanumeric character
       |-> Makes sure the start of the string is a mix of single @ or alphanumeric characters
       |   It has to start with an alphanumeric character
```